# Reformat JSON object using Dart

Tags: json, dart

I need to standardize the object response key/values so that they are easier to parse/traverse using the tool I'm integrating.

Starting with the following JSON:

```
{
  "status": true,
  "body": {
    "phone": "+1 937-830-1167",
    "address": "2323 kuhku",
    "linkedin": "uhku",
    "twitter": "uhukh",
    "education": "weeww",
    "work_experience": "wewaew",
    "write_something_about_you": "yugtyt",
    "why_you_think_you_are_good_for_this_job": "kuhhuk",
    "write_your_assignment_question": "kuhghuhghj",
    "upload_your_attachment": null,
    "upload_your_resume_here": null
  }
}
```

Using Dart, what would be the best way to reformat as shown?

```
{
  "status": true,
  "body": {
    "answers":[
        {
            "label": "phone",
            "answer":"+1 937-830-1167"
        },
        {
            "label": "address",
            "answer":"2323 kuhku"
        },
        {
            "label": "linkedin",
            "answer": "uhku"
        },
        {
            "label": "twitter",
            "answer": "uhku"
        },
        {
            "label": "education",
            "answer": "uhku"
        },
        {
            "label": "work_experience",
            "answer": "uhku"
        },
        {
            "label": "write_something_about_you",
            "answer": "uhku"
        },
        {
            "label": "why_you_think_you_are_good_for_this_job",
            "answer": "uhku"
        },
        {
            "label": "write_your_assignment_question",
            "answer": "uhku"
        },
        {
            "label": "upload_your_attachment",
            "answer": "uhku"
        },
        {
            "label": "write_something_about_you",
            "answer": "upload_your_resume_here"
        }
    ]
    }
}
```

I'm somewhat limited by the tool I'm using so this will make it much easier to parse the JSON object with JSON Path as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something that should be easily doable as:

```dart
var json = ... your json ...;
var result = {
  "status": json["status"],
  "body": [for (var e in json["body"].entries) 
    {"label": e.key, "answer": e.value}
  ]
};
```

Create a new JSON object with the same `"status"` and a `"body"` which is a *list* instead of a map, and for each *entry* in the original map, create a JSON object with a `"label"` and `"answer"` taken from the key and value of the map entry.